# How to dispose browser in CEF to load the next one in

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm having some `CefSharp` issues on my `WinForm` application, after reading the `CefSharp` guide and doing some extensive googling i'm unable to solve this issue.

Basically, i'm feeding through a couple of URLs to a second form, I am looking to load `url1.com` into a panel containing the browser `panelBrowserMain.Controls.Add(browser);` once i'm finished with that url i'll load in `url2.com` extract the data then close the form altogether.

I 'm not looking for multiple browser panels just to re-use the main one.

**Code:**

```
        public FormBrowser(string[] sitesList, string mode, FormMain formMain, Project _project, Func<string, Tuple<string, string, string>> getUserPassEmail)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CefSharpSettings.SubprocessExitIfParentProcessClosed = true;
            if (!Cef.IsInitialized) // Check before Initialized.
            {
                // Init CEF.
                CefSettings settings = new CefSettings
                {
                    CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), @"cache")
                    //UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:20.0) Gecko/20121202 Firefox/20.0"
                };
                Cef.Initialize(settings);
            }

            _sitesToProcess = sitesList; // Array of sites [ url1.com , url2.com ] etc.
            _modeToUse = mode;           // Mode either [REG] or [LAP].
            _formMain = formMain;        // Main UI object.

            foreach (var siteToProcess in sitesList) {
                string _mode = _modeToUse == "MODE_REG" ? "-[REG]" : "-[LAP]";
                // Load the macro code to use depending on the mode selected.
                string[] _macroCode = File.ReadAllLines(@"engines\" + siteToProcess + _mode);
                browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(siteToProcess);
                InitializeChromeBrowser(browser, _mode, _macroCode, siteToProcess, _sitesToProcess.Count(), _project, getUserPassEmail);
            }
        }

        public bool InitializeChromeBrowser(ChromiumWebBrowser browser, string _modeToUse, string[] _macroCode, string _site, int _sitesCount, Project _project, Func<string, Tuple<string, string, string>> getUserPassEmail)
        {
            bool complete = false;
            try
            {
                    if (_modeToUse == "-[REG]")
                    {
                        foreach (string _macroCodeReg in _macroCode)
                        {
                            string[] code = _macroCodeReg.Split('|');

                            switch (code[0])
                            {
                                case "RJ_U":
                                    string cleanUrl = code[1].Replace("{HOSTNAME}", _site);
                                    browser.Load(cleanUrl);
                                    panelBrowserMain.Controls.Add(browser);
                                    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                                    browserMain.Text = cleanUrl;
                                    browser.AddressChanged += Browser_AddressChanged;
                                    break;
                                case "RJ_I":
                                    browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(GetAndReplaceMacro(code[1], _project));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                    complete = true;
                    } 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
            return complete;
        }

        private void FormBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Text = "Chrome Version: [ " + Cef.CefSharpVersion + " ]";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Helpers.DebugLogging($"[{DateTime.Now}]-[{ex}]");
            }
        }
```

What I can't seem to work out is, once a url loads and i visually can see what needs extracted done, how do I (or cefsharp) know the work is done and to dispose of the window? currently it just hangs there after the extracted data is taken, on `FormClose` i do `browser.Dispose();` but that requires it to be manually clicked on as opposed to automatically disposing itself (if this makes sense!)

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Do you need multiple ChromiumWebBrowser instances?  They're relatively expensive to create, reusing the same one would be preferable. The simplest option is to use LoadingStateChanged and execute your JavaScript, when your done load the next url. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript remove the ChromiumWebBrowser from it's parent before calling Dispose.

Comment: If you don't require user interaction with the browser then the OffScreen version is probably better suited, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/87/CefSharp.OffScreen.Example/Program.cs for an example.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the help! OffScreen does seem a better option in this case, i literally read the commands from an external file, no user interaction needed i will look into this too :) thanks again Alex.